# Do I need Visual Studio 2012 to write .NET 4.5 Applications?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Do I need Visual Studio 2012 to write .NET 4.5 Applications? Ive seen some confusing info regarding this so I'm hoping for a simple answer.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe so, but you do need it to write Windows8 apps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strictly speaking? No. You could always use the command line compiler, or create project files and run MSBuild directly.

Realistically? Yup.

In particular, if your question is *really* "Can I use C# 5 and target .NET 4.5 from Visual Studio 2010?", the answer is basically no. Obviously there were the CTPs around C# 5 which integrated with VS2010, but they definitely had bugs in around async, and you really *shouldn't* be using them.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks Jon.