# Can I use EF5 and stay with Visual Studio 2010 for the moment?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-5

I would like to use the latest Entity Framework (EF5), but not like to buy a new Version of Visual Studio yet.

**Would it be possible to use EF5 with VS2010? And with what restrictions, if any?**

Notes:

- I have read on [Brice's Blog](http://brice-lambson.blogspot.ch/2012/10/unicorn-myths-debunked-entity-framework.html) that EF5 can be used with .NET 4.0. Is this the way to go for me?
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12254230/79485) is somewhat related, but I am not requiring a .NET Version, but a EF Version (which may in turn require a specific .NET version however).
- [This question is very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12921194/79485), again if focuses more on the .NET version, not on VS Version.

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems a clear, answerable question to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are able to use EF5 with VS2010.

EF5 can be used against .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 applications.

as per this blog post on the EF Team Blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/08/15/ef5-released.aspx

> This version of the NuGet package is fully compatible with Visual
>   Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 and can be used for applications
>   targeting .NET 4.0 and 4.5.
>
> Some features are only available when writing an application that
>   targets .NET 4.5. This includes enum support, spatial data types,
>   table-valued functions and the performance improvements.

The restrictions are around the target .NET version of your application, not visual studio itself.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the blog post!